# Customizing The Flashed Error Format - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, overriding, laravel-validation, laravel-5.3

I want to customize the format of flashed error message, that is recieved after i do something like `$this->validator($request->all())->validate();`

For an ajax request, it responds with:

```
{
    "name": [
        "The name field is required."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The email field is required."
    ],
}
```

But i want it to look like

```
{
    "status": "fail",
    "errors": {
        "name": [
            "The name field is required."
        ],
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ],
    }
}
```

I read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation) under *Customizing The Flashed Error Format* and added `formatValidationErrors` method in my `Controller` class, but it's not making any difference.

```
public function formatValidationErrors(Validator $validator)
{
    return ['status' => 'fail', 'errors' => $validator->errors()->getMessages()];
}
```

It's not changing even if i change `formatValidationErrors` method in the original `Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests` trait

I'm forced have to build this format in all request calls and so there's code-duplication. It would be nice if i could just call `$this->validator($request->all())->validate()` and it automatically formats as per my requirement.

Comment: Just wanted to say, the original structure provided by laravel is actually much more useful than the variant you are looking for :)

Comment: Edited my question for "Why i need this?"

Comment: The reason to have two levels of validation errors is because you can have more than one validation error for a single field (for example, username is too short, and username contain illegal characters). I would suggest stick with the original structure that generated from laravel, and to consume it, do a simple adapter to convert it to a desired structure.

Comment: agreed. I also think it's better to stick with original error structure. Still i need to wrap it in an array. Edited and simplified my question.

Answer (score 0):

The way to change it is to create a class that extends Validator and override the addError method. Here's a sample code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Validators;

use Illuminate\Support\MessageBag;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class RestValidator extends Validator {

    /**
     * Add an error message to the validator's collection of messages.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  string  $rule
     * @param  array   $parameters
     * @return void
     */
    protected function addError($attribute, $rule, $parameters)
    {
        $message = $this->getMessage($attribute, $rule);

        $message = $this->doReplacements($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters);

        $customMessage = new MessageBag();

        $customMessage->merge(['code' => strtolower($rule.'_rule_error')]);
        $customMessage->merge(['message' => $message]);

        $this->messages->add($attribute, $customMessage);
    }
}
```

Now you can structure the validation in your controllers like so:

```
$rules = [
    // Your rules here
];

$attributes = [
    // The attributes you're checking here
];

$validator = Validator::make($attributes, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $errorMessage = [
        'status' => 'fail',
        'errors' => $validator->errors()
    ];

    return $errorMessage;
}

// The rest of your code goes here
```

Comment: I'm sure there is an easier approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your model,

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    if (($this->ajax() && !$this->pjax()) || $this->wantsJson()) {
        $errors = array('status' => 'fail', 'errors' => $errors);
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }
    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
        ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
        ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

It will result as you expected,

```
{
"status": "fail",
  "error": {
    "name": [
      "The name field is required."
    ],
    "email": [
      "The email field is required"
    ]
  }
}
```